# How to use text-overflow properly to format text?

Tags: html, css

I have the following html element:

```
<h2>Download "<div id="title"></div>" for...</h2>
```

I want to insert a title with jquery inside the `<div id="title"></div>` and It should look like this way:

> Download "The title is soo long long long ..." for ...

with this css/less:

```
#title{
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
```

But It looks this way:

> Download "
>
> The title is soo long long long ...
>
> " for ...

I should see one line of text with splitted title, but instead I see three lines of text. How can I force to place the whole text to one line? Thanks!

Comment: I think you wouldn't have this problem if instead of a `div` you used ie a `span`... You wouldn't even need special CSS handling for that aspect at all..

Comment: Why are you using a div instead of a span?

Comment: @Joum: what about setting the width?

Comment: @Itay for that it is not enough, but that isn't showed as a requirement in th OP... Hence, I explicitly mention _that aspect_. And by _that aspect_ I obviously mean the line breaking, not the text ellipsing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way would be to use `span` element, and set to `inline-block`

http://jsbin.com/imutem/4/edit

```
#title{
   display:inline-block;
   vertical-align:bottom;
   overflow: hidden;
   width:200px;
   white-space: nowrap;
   text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
```

HTML:

```
<h2>Download "<span id="title"></span>" for...</h2>
```

Comment: Why only `span` when you are using `display: inline-block` later?

Comment: @Mr_Green `span` elements are by default `inline` level elements, setting it to `display-block` (which is Xbrowser for `span` elements) you can than use `overflow:hidden;` What is not clear? You know the difference between `inline-block` and `block` right? Using `span` inside `h2` (def:block-level) elements is always the right thing to do.

Comment: @Mr_Green also semantically if he is using this inside a `p` tag, using `div` will be incorrect, so you should use `span` for such things

Comment: The only problem I still have, that Firefox aligns the text differently than chrome or safari. Is there a way to conditional set the alignment based on the browser type?

Answer (score 2):

You are using `text-overflow: ellipsis;` which works when you've a single line, so you don't have to use `for...` actually, it will make something like `sentence...for...`. Also `div` is a block level element so you will have to use `display: inline-block;` and assign a fix width for your element.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/HtF7y/) (Thanks to the comments below, though I was working on it..)

```
#title{
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: bottom; /* This is important to align text right in the line */
}
```

Also, I would like to point out that you are using an `id` there, and id has to be unique, so just make sure you don't repeat, better use a class instead. Also for these purposes, `span` will be a better element to go for..

Comment: I think you should make that inline-block and set its width

Answer (score -1):

use `white-space:nowrap;` and `overflow:hidden;` in #title